# Play a beep that loop and change the frequency/speed

Tags: ios, loops, audio, frequency, playback

I am creating an iphone application that use audio.
I want to play a beep sound that loop indefinitely.

I found an easy way to do that using the upper layer `AVAudioPlayer` and the `numberOfLoops` set to "`-1`". It works fine.

But now I want to play this audio and be able to change the rate / speed. It may works like the sound played by a car when approaching an obstacle. At the beginning the beep has a low frequency and this frequency accelerate till reaching a continuous sound biiiiiiiiiiiip ...
It seems this is not feasible using the high layer `AVAudioPlayer`, but even looking at `AudioToolBox` I found no solution.

Any help?

Comment: Does the sound continue to increase in pitch over the whole period?  If so its going to get out of audible range quickly.  Have you considered making more than one sound and load then when necessary?

Comment: No the sound will not increase over the whole period. I have a maximum and a minimum limit and I want to be able to increase or decrease the rate / frequency of the audio playback between those limit.

Comment: Do you mean rate at which beeps are played or the frequency of the beep waveform? The former is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Dave Dribin's [A440 sample application](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2010/04/26/announcing_a440/), which plays a constant 440 Hz tone on the iPhone / iPad.  It uses the lower-level Audio Queue Services, but it does what you're asking (short of the realtime tone adjustment, which would just require a tweak of the existing code).